# Consulta SQL para página ASP.NET com C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, select

No site do meu cliente, possuo uma consulta SQL que traz o resultado de nível de prontidão de vários colaboradores. Só que, por enquanto, só consigo transferir pra página o resultado da consulta em um GridView:

**CONSULTA SQL**

```sql
SELECT codigoAvaliacao, codigoColaborador, nomeColaborador, nivelProntidao 
FROM TableAvaliacoes
```

**EXEMPLO DE RESULTADO**

```
codigoAvaliacao | codigoColaborador | nomeColaborador | nivelProntidao
--------------- | ----------------- | --------------- | --------------
1               | 1                 | Fulano          | 90
2               | 3                 | João            | 75
3               | 4                 | Ciclano         | 83,5
4               | 6                 | Beltrano        | 44,44
5               | 10                | Silva           | 68,11
```

Minha ideia era trazer o resultado dessa consulta de outro modo, associando com uma figura chamada de NineBox. Ela coloca os nomes nos quadrados dependendo do nível de prontidão. Eis um exemplo da figura como eu achei na internet:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí, por enquanto, só consegui colocar o código HTML da tabela com as devidas cores:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: black; background-color: yellow"><center id="names1"></center></td>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(151,195,82)"><center id="names2"></center></td>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(12,133,54)"><center id="names3"></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(245,154,73)"><center id="names4"></center></td>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: black; background-color: yellow"><center id="names5"></center></td>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(151,195,82)"><center id="names6"></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: white; background-color: red"><center id="names7"></center></td>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: black; background-color: rgb(245,154,73)"><center id="names8"></center></td>
        <td width="200" height="200" style="color: black; background-color: yellow"><center id="names9"></center></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

O que eu precisaria então a partir dessa consulta SQL fosse criada outra e viesse algo assim (supondo que os resultados fossem os nomes da imagem ao invés do exemplo do resultado), com os nomes de cada quadrado separados pela tabulação:

```
QUADRADO | NOMES
-------- | -----
1        | Francisco
2        | NULL
3        | Vera
4        | NULL
5        | Alice<br>Alexandre<br>Marcos<br>Madalena
6        | Ângela<br>José 
7        | Maria
8        | João<br>Pedro
9        | Benedito<br>Carla<br>David
```

O que eu coloco como consulta SQL pra esse caso?

Comment: Onde estão os valores abaixo e acima do esperado? Está utilizando o que? Asp.NET MVC, WebForms, Aspx, etc?

Comment: @Randrade Pensei que cada quadrado ou faixa tem valores de faixa um pouco diferentes:

0 a 20% - QUADRADO 7
20 a 40% - QUADRADO 4
40 a 60% - QUADRADO 8
60 a 65% - QUADRADO 1
65 a 70% - QUADRADO 5
70 a 75% - QUADRADO 9
75 a 82% - QUADRADO 2
82 a 90% - QUADRADO 6
90 a 100% - QUADRADO 3

E a linguagem é Asp.NET MVC com o C#. Está no título.

Comment: qual o model q esta a passar para a view? podes trabalhar simplesmente com a lista que passas para a view

Comment: Se vc prover como vc avalia oque é alto ou baixo e quanto é o esperado é fácil. Por exemplo calculando esses valores, fazendo join com uma tabela de valores dos quadrados (para separar as pessoas) e depois aplicando uma CTE para "acumular" os nomes. Apesar de que o correto mesmo seria passar apenas a lista de nomes e suas categorias e deixar a UI "inseri-los" nos quadrados, até pq vc pode querer aplicar formatações diferentes para cada quadrado dependendo da quantidade de nomes em cada um.